# Create a column from existing columns using pandas , numpy

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a new column using existing columns  by performing simple arithmetic combinations of values. This is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Dataset():
    def __init__(self, input):
        self.choice = input
        self.file = 0

    def read(self):
        if self.choice == ("1"):
            self.file = pd.read_csv('1')
            self.file.plot(kind='bar')
            print(df)

i = (input("Pick a DataSet= "))
df = Dataset(i)
df.read()
plt.show()
```

I have tried these suggestions:

```
        #'Dataset' object does not support item assignment --> df['New Column'] = ['Reference Area'] + ['Ratio']
        #TypeError: 'Dataset' object is not subscriptable -> df['NEW COL'] = df[['Reference Area', 'Ratio']].sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `df` is of type `DataSet` not `pandas`. The `pandas` variable is inside the DataSet class (variable `self.file`) so you should be able to do something like:

```
df.file['New Column'] = df.file['Reference Area'] + df.file['Ratio']
```

from outside the class. Alternatively, you could add a method to the class to do this:

```
def create_new_column(self):
    self.file['New Column'] = self.file['Reference Area'] + self.file['Ratio']
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could say `df = Dataset(i).file` and then perform computations on `df`.